# Regex. Notepad++ How to replace a line with itself and an additional symbol/word?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Say I have a regex search that matches what I'm looking for. I need to replace the match with itself plus an additonal word.

Line example:

John

`^.*John.*$`    This matches what I want (the word John). This is what I need after the replacement:

John abc123

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to capture everything with `.*`

Just use:

**regex**

```
John
```

**replace**

```
$0 abc123
```

---

If you want to avoid turning `Johnathan` into `John abc123athan` then use word boundaries:

**regex**

```
\bJohn\b
```

**replace**

```
$0 abc123
```

---

One of the biggest issues with using `^.*John.*$` whatsoever is that if there are two `John`s in a single line then only the last one will be replaced.

> John has a friend named John

would become

> John has a friend named John abc123

Comment: What If I wanted to replace the line containing my match with itself and the new word? The position of the new word should be in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You want regex capture groups.  Then you can use the capture group as part of what you replace in the string.  I'm not sure what syntax Notepad++ uses, so you may need different syntax than this example.  See regex101.com to test your regex.

For your example, in python, you can use () to specify the capture group, and r'\1' to use capture group 1 in the new text:

```
text = 'hello John, how are you'
text = re.sub('([A-Z]\w*)', r'\1' + ' abc123', text)
print(text)
# hello John abc123, how are you
```

Comment: You seem to dig that stuff, so I'll follow up: why does specific regex I'm using (not the above one) work in Sublime Text but refuses to work in other (few tested) text editors that support regex?

Comment: I'm guessing that the other text editors use a different syntax for regex.  You could search for what syntax each text editor uses, or just use the text editor that you already got to work.

Comment: What If I wanted to replace the line containing my match with itself and the new word? The position of the new word should be in a new line

Comment: I don't understand what the output would look like.  Also, you're trying to do this in a text editor, not with python?

Comment: You are right, I am using a text editor mostly Notepad++ but also Sublime Text.